# In a Web page, how can I tick all checkboxes in selection?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, internet-explorer, forms

I am using a webmail (Outlook Web Access).

I have a Web page : in my mailbox, I have many messages.

I select 30 lines.

Now, I want **something** that would tick the 30 checkboxes that are in my selection.

I want to right-click my selection and to choose an action *Tick all checkboxes*.

How can I have that ?

An extension for Firefox would be nice.

I would appreciate an extension for Chrome too.

Thank you.

*[Edit]* I would like a solution for IE too.

Answer (score 4):

For Firefox, use the CheckFox extension:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/checkfox/

Comment: This looks very interesting! But this extension is in version "0.9.2.1-signed".

Comment: The linked extension, Checkfox, no longer exists, although I was able to find an equivalent extension (written by someone who also needed a replacement for Checkfox):
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/checkthemall/

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook webmail you can find on the top of the page, a box to check all: "Show: all".

Comment: I know that I have a checkbox to tick all messages. But I want to tick only a range of messages.

Answer (score 0):

For **`Outlook Web Mail`** (**`Hotmail`**, **`mail.live.com`**), you can "check" the checkboxes for a range of messages with two clicks.

1. In the "normal" way, click the checkbox for a message at the "top" (or "bottom") of the range of messages you want to "check". It doesn't matter if that checkbox was already "checked" or if it was "unchecked"... one click to "set" or "unset" the "checkmark" will do.
2. If necessary, use the web-page scrollbars to bring the other end of the range of messages that you want to "check" into view.
3. Hold down the "Shift" key on the keyboard, and click the checkbox on the message at the other end of the range ("bottom" or "top") of messages you want to "check".

All the messages between the first message that you clicked, and the last message that you "shift-clicked" will become "checked". It doesn't matter if any messages between the first and last message was already "checked" or "unchecked", all messages within the range will become "checked". You can adjust the "end" of the range of messages "checked" by keeping the "shift" key held down and clicking the checkbox on different messages to expand or contract the range of "checked" messages.

**Limitations:**

- If you repeat this proceedure on the same set of messages, the messages will just stay "checked" instead of becoming "unchecked" as you might expect.
- If you attempt to repeat this proceedure on a different set of messages (which might include a subset of the first set, or not), the "First" set (range) of messages will become "unchecked", and then the "New" set (range) of messages will all become "checked".
- Similarly, when "checking" a range of messages in this way, any messages outside of that range of messages that was already "checked" will become "unchecked".

So, you can only "check" one range of messages in this way. You cannot "check" multiple ranges of messages or a range of messages along with individually "checked" messages. You ***can*** "check" one range of messages, then individually "check" any other messages that you want "checked".

Comment: Thank you @Kevin for this very complete answer. I will definitely try this !

Comment: Alas, this does not work. Neither with Chrome nor with Firefox.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco - I tested this with **`IE (version 9)`** and **`Firefox (version 19.0.2)`** and it is working for me (I don't have **`Chrome`** installed here). I am opening ***http://outlook.com*** (or ***http://hotmail.com*** or ***http://mail.live.com/***) which redirects to ***https://blu175.mail.live.com***. I assume that's the web-page you're talking about. What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Kevin, I have Firefox 26 on Windows.